# Which one should be preferred 1:1,0 or nullable fields on one table on relational database?

Tags: entity-framework, database-design, orm, ef-code-first, relational-database

I use Azure Sql and Entity-Framework Code First.

I have `Transaction` Table. There are 4 types which are `buy/sell`, `withdrawal`, `deposit` and `fee`.

For example, I need `DepositCode` for deposit transactions but this column will be null for others. Also I need `ItemPrice` and `ItemAmount` for buy/sell but it will be null for other types.

Example `Transaction` Table

```
 public class Transaction
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public int Type { get; set; }
        public string DepositCode { get; set; }
        public decimal? ItemPrice { get; set; }
        public decimal? ItemAmount { get; set; }
        public string WithdrawalIban { get; set; }
    }
```

or

```
 public class Transaction
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public int Type { get; set; }
        public DepositTransaction DepositTransaction { get; set; }
        public WithdrawalTransaction BuyAndSellTransaction { get; set; }
        public WithdrawalTransaction WithdrawalTransaction { get;set; }
    }


 public class DepositTransaction
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
        public string DepositCode { get; set; }
    }


 public class WithdrawalTransaction
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
        public string WithdrawalIban { get; set; }
    }


 public class BuySellTransaction
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemPrice { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemAmount { get; set; }
    }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<WithdrawalTransaction>()
        .HasRequired(wt => wt.Transaction)
        .WithOptional(tr => tr.WithdrawalTransaction);

        modelBuilder.Entity<DepositTransaction>()
      .HasRequired(db => db.Transaction)
      .WithOptional(tr=> tr.DepositTransaction);

        modelBuilder.Entity<BuySellTransaction>()
      .HasRequired(bs => bs.Transaction)
      .WithOptional(tr => tr.BuySellTransaction);

    }
```

Which one should be preferred ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer nullable fields when possible, which is the implementation in *table per class hierarchy* mappings. Using this approach EF will store all transactions objects in one table and will use a discriminator column to manage type loading for you. That said I would refactor your model as follows:

```
public abstract class Transaction
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
}


public class DepositTransaction : Transaction
{
    public string DepositCode { get; set; }
}


public class WithdrawalTransaction : Transaction
{
    public string WithdrawalIban { get; set; }
}


public class BuySellTransaction : Transaction
{
    public decimal ItemPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal ItemAmount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If I want to show all transactions to user, what will be query ? Can you give an example.

Comment: For this scenario you can use projection to create the desired output, or even you may create a view in the database and map it to an readonly entity for reporting or listing purposes.

Comment: Also you can change Transaction class to be non abstract class. Queries emitted against the base class will retrieve records from the database table corresponding to base and derived types.

Comment: Thanks I'm using tph and tpt (for very rare datas) at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You actually have only three transactions: buy/sell, deposit/withdrawal, fee. The difference between buy and sell is that the amount is positive for buy and negative for sell. Same goes for deposit and withdrawal.

```
create table Transactions(
    ID         bigint identity primary key,
    XType      char( 1 ) not null, -- 'B': buy/sell, 'D': dep/with, 'F': fee
    Amount     money not null,
    constraint CK_Transaction_Type check( XType in( 'B', 'D', 'F' ),
    constraint UQ_Transaction_Type unique( ID, XType )
);
```

The other tables (or subtables if you want to think of them as such) would look like this:

```
create table BuySellTrans(
    TransID    bigint not null,
    TransType  char( 1 ) not null,
    ...,   -- other info regarding purchase or sale
    constraint CK_BuySellTrans_BuySellType check( TransType = 'B' )
    constraint FK_BuySellTrans_Trans foreign key( TransID, TransType )
        references Transactions( ID, XType )
);
```

As for the code, the best way may be to have an abstract super class Transaction with subclasses BuySell, DepositWithdrawal and Fee. I would also provide some convenient views named, coincidentally, BuySell, DepositWithdrawal and Fee. These views would provide a joined dataset of the Transactions table with the appropriate subtable. Triggers on the views (your system allowing) would simplify the application code greatly as each subclass would query and manipulate only through the views. The code wouldn't even need to know about the physical layout in the database.

Comment: what is the purpose of creating `constraint UQ_Transaction_Type unique( ID, XType )` , isn't it enough to create the ID `identity primary key` ?

Comment: Yes, the primary key is all that is needed to make each row unique -- in Transactions. But we also need uniqueness at Type level to enforce referential integrity from the different Type tables. This enforces uniqueness not only in Transactions, but all across the various subtables of different Type. For example, Transactions entry with ID 1001 is entered. There cannot be another ID of 1001 in that table. But 1001 could be entered into BuySellTrans, DepWithdrawals or Fees table. Not good. The added unique constraint limits which table can contain ID 1001 -- the one with the same Type.